# how to do simple calculations on numbers in text

Tags: text-editing, calc

I have a Json file containing a quite a few coordinates like `{x: 400, y:200}`
And I want to change the numbers for the y values in something like `y:y_default + 120`. (y_default = 80). Is there a quick way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that interactively by `query-replace-regexp` with embedded Elisp in the replacement string.

1. Go to the beginning of the file.
2. Type <kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd>.
3. Input `{x: \([0-9]+\), y:\([0-9]+\)}` as search regexp.
4. Input `{x: \1, y:y_default + \,(- (read \2) 80)}` as replacement string.
5. Answer the queries of `query-replace-regexp` as appropriate.

The escape sequence `\,(...)` evaluates the sexp behind the `\,` and replaces itself with the result. You can use the usual references to subgroups as `\1` and `\2` in the sexp. They are interpolated as strings.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! An extra reason to pickup lisp again. What was your reason to use (read str) above (string-to-number str)?

Comment: @drjerry `\1` is interpolated as string but we need it as number for the minus operator. The `read` employs the Elisp reader to transform the string into a number. You could also use `string-to-number`.